# Having trouble with while loops and collecting user input

Tags: python, if-statement, input, while-loop

Hi I'm working on an assignment where I make a self-service program. I'm having trouble trying to incorporate a while loop while collecting user input. I want my code to collect an amount of money (entered by the user) and prompt the user on how much more they need to pay. Once the amount paid exceeds the amount due, I want to continue with the rest of my code. This is what I have so far but the loop stops after 2 inputs, even if the user has not paid enough.

```
elif paid < TotalCost:
  due = TotalCost - paid
  while due > 0:
    print("You need to pay $",round(due,2)," more.")
    morepaid=float(input("Enter the amount paid: $"))
    if morepaid>TotalCost:
      change= morepaid- TotalCost
      print("Change due: $",round(change,2))
      print(" ")
      print("Thank you for visiting McDonald's")
  
    elif due== 0:
      print("Change due: $0.00")
      print(" ")
      print("Thank you for visiting McDonald's")
    else:
      due -= morepaid
```

Comment: You need separate variables for the total paid and each individual payment. Each time you do `paid = float(input(...))` you're losing the total.

Comment: @Barmar I tried separating the variables but the loop still doesn't work.

Comment: Why are you adding `morepaid` to itself instead of `totalpaid`? It should be `totalPaid += morepaid`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply subtract the amount paid from `due`, you don't need another variable `totalpaid`.

```
elif paid < totalCost:
    due = totalCost - paid:
    while due > 0:
        print("You need to pay $",round(due,2)," more.")
        morepaid=float(input("Enter the amount paid: $"))
        due -= morepaid
```

Comment: Thank you, this helped fix my loop issue but I can't get it to work with the rest of my code. I want to be able to calculate change if the input is higher than the amount due. For example, if the user needs to pay $4.50 more and they pay $5 it prints a message like "Change due: $0.50".

Comment: After this code you can check if `due < 0`. Then the negative of `due` is the change owed.